# Using and manipulating date variable inside AWK

Tags: bash, date, awk

I assume that there may be a better way to do it but the only one I came up with was using AWK.

I have a file with name convention like following:

`testfile_2016_03_01.txt`

Using one command I am trying to shift it by one day `testfile_20160229.txt`

I started from using:

```
file=testfile_2016_03_01.txt
IFS="_"
arr=($file)
datepart=$(echo ${arr[1]}-${arr[2]}-${arr[3]} | sed 's/.txt//')
date -d "$datepart - 1 days" +%Y%m%d
```

the above works fine, but I really wanted to do it in AWK. The only thing I found was how to use "date" inside AWK

```
new_name=$(echo ${file##.*} | awk -F'_' ' {
"date '+%Y%m%d'" | getline date;
print date
}')
echo $new_name
```

okay so two things happen here. For some reason `$4` also contains `.txt` even though I removed it(?) `##.*`

And the main problem is I don't know how to pass the variables to that date, the below doesn't work

```
`awk -F'_' '{"date '-d "2016-01-01"' '+%Y%m%d'" | getline date; print date}')
```

ideally I want `2016-01-01` to be variables coming from the file name `$2-$3-$4` and substract 1 day but I think I'm getting way too many single and double quotes here and my brain is losing..

Comment: Remove from end: `${file%%.*}` instead of `##` (or just one `%` as there is just one `.` anyway).

Comment: Do you have or can you get GNU awk?

Comment: Thanks BenjaminW, it works (though I don't know why ## didn't, I do have it in different scripts). @EdMorton I do have gawk yes

Comment: `##` removes matching from the start, you'd use it to get, e.g., an extension or basename: `var='/abc/def/file.txt'; echo "${var#*.}"; echo "${var##*/}"` returns `txt` and `file.txt`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equivalent `awk` command:

```
file='testfile_2016_03_01.txt'
echo "${file%.*}" |
awk -F_ '{cmd="date -d \"" $2"-"$3"-"$4 " -1 days\"" " +%Y%m%d";
          cmd | getline date; close(cmd); print date}'

20160229
```

Comment: Worked as a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

WIth GNU awk for time functions:

```
$ file=testfile_2016_03_01.txt
$ awk -v file="$file" 'BEGIN{ split(file,d,/[_.]/); print strftime(d[1]"_%Y%m%d."d[5],mktime(d[2]" "d[3]" "d[4]" 12 00 00")-(24*60*60)) }'
testfile_20160229.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
file='testfile_2016_03_01.txt'
IFS='_.' read -ra a <<< "$file"
date -d "${a[1]}${a[2]}${a[3]} -1 day" "+${a[0]}_%Y%m%d.${a[4]}"
```